# Magento W3C validation for css link

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I am working to validate W3C errors in the magento shop.It is including the css in theme's `page.xml` by using the code:

```
<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/styles.css</stylesheet></action>
```

When check at W3C validator it give error:

> Element link is missing required attribute property

I did search for this error and found a sloution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18549726/element-link-is-missing-required-attribute-property) that i can use `property='stylesheet'` to fix the error.

Now the question is how to use `property='stylesheet'` here with magento css include code?

Comment: IMHO, W3C validation was cool 10 years ago when everybody had those shiny badges on their site, but any more it is just a waste of time and effort for little to no real gain. This is especially true with CMS and e-commerce platforms that dynamically generate HTML. It does help, however, in finding areas that could be improved upon.

Comment: @JosephLeedy I strongly disagree with you, W3C validation is an important point, especially in terms of performance. I reckon it's worth doing it if you can

Comment: any solution to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to just put element between action method like this `<property>property='stylesheet'</property>`

For example :-

```
<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/styles.css</stylesheet><property>property='stylesheet'</property></action>
```

Or if you want to add it in all css links then just copy `Head.php`  from here :

> app\code\core\Mage\Page\Block\Html

And paste it here :

> app\code\local\Mage\Page\Block\Html

And find the below mentioned line **public function getCssJsHtml()** in this method

```
$html .= $this->_prepareStaticAndSkinElements('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="%s"%s />'."\n",
```

Now you can add your property here like :

```
 $html .= $this->_prepareStaticAndSkinElements('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" property="stylesheet" href="%s"%s />'."\n",
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: applied the fix and clear cache, worked fine.thanks